# How to write custom casting method in Java

Tags: java, casting

I have a Java class that has a few members. I want to write a custom cast for it. I was wondering how is it possible to do so?

Let's assume the class is as follows:

```
class Person {
   private int age;
   private float weight;

   // getters and setters and etc
}
```

I would like the `int` cast to return the member `age` of an object, and the `float` cast to return the `weight` of an object.

For instance:

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // create an object
        Person P = new Person();
        P.setAge(21);
        P.setWeight(88.0);

        // case 1: casting object to an existing data type
        int personAge = (int) P; // would return the age
        float personWeight = (float) P;  // would return the weight

        // case 2: casting an existing data type to an object
        Person P2 = (Person) personAge; // this would create an instance of the object whose age is assigned and weight is not assigned

    }
}
```

I was wondering if it is possible to do the opposite. In particular, casting `int` to `Person` would return an instance of `Person` that its `age` is assigned and similarly for `float`.

I know this question may not have an answer. But because I did not find any useful results in my search, I decided to ask it.

P.S. I understand that for a `String`, the `toString` method would take care of case 1.

Comment: You can't define new cast operations. The existing ones are all defined in the JLS. You can add methods like `toInt`, `fromInt`, `toFloat` and `fromFloat` though.

Comment: Casting can be done only for value to value but in your case Object has many fields, how casting will understand that it has to do for age only ? As @Sweeper said, you can do like that, however what is the need as we can have getter and setter methods.

Comment: You may want to use Groovy for such cases (assuming the cast caller will be in groovy too). Otherwise you can implement `asInt`, `asFloat`... methods

Comment: Although its not allowed. Even if it's allowed, don't you think its quite confusing to map values with appropriate castings?

Comment: @Sambit: Actually, it doesn't matter if the class has many members of the same type because I wanted to implement/overload the cast so that it decides which one to return.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't overload the cast operator. Java doesn't support it and probably never will.

To convert a single value to an instance of the desired class, we use static factory methods.

```
public static Person fromAge(int age) {
    return new Person(age);
}
```

*They often return a partially constructed object. In the snippet above, a newly constructed person has only `age` set: other fields will have their default values.*

To do the opposite, we use getters.

```
public int getAge() {
    return age;
}
```

> However, since `toString` is already there, it makes sense to add other data types as well.

`toInt` makes no sense when it's applied to me (as an instance of the `Person` class). It could be my height, my weight, my age, a number of times I went to a bathroom today, etc. I can't represent myself by one int number, neither can a large majority of classes.

On the other hand, `toString` can do this job pretty well: I can give you (read *return*) a summary of my hobbies, my biometric information, even my picture. Or I can leave it to the default implementation, which still would satisfactorily represent an object.

Comment: So, it is not possible. However, since `toString` is already there, it makes sense to add other data types as well.

Comment: @orezvani what data types do you want to add?

Comment: @orezvani the toString method is only there to help with logging/debugging. It prints a nice representation of your object. I don't think that it does make sense to add other data types (other than the way specified in this answer). If you had multiple field of type int then a toInt method wouldn't make sense, it is better to just have an accessor method for each of your fields

Comment: @orezvani everything can be "textually represented" (as a `String`), but it's not true for any other type

Comment: @orezvani `toInt` makes no sense when it's applied to me (as an instance of the `Person` class). It could be my height, my weight, my age, a number of times I went to a bathroom today, etc. I can't represent myself by one `int` number. On the other hand, `toString` can do this work pretty well: I can give you (read *return*) a summary of my hobbies, my biometric information, even my picture.

Comment: Actually ... "[`toString`] prints a nice representation of your object" ... only if you have implemented it to do that.  The default implementation (in Object) prints an ugly representation that *doesn't* tell you anything about the object's state other than its class name.

Comment: @StephenC Though it's ugly unless overridden, it still represents an object by its hash and class name. In case of `toFloat`, it would be a random number or `.0f`: both make no sense.

Comment: I'm not disputing that `toFloat` would be meaningless.  What I am saying is that `Object::toString` is not a nice representation, and for many (naive) uses it is not a meaningful representation ... as illustrated by many SO questions about printing arrays, for example.  (Something is only meaningful when people understand the meaning ...)

Answer (score 0):

You wouldn't use a cast for this just write methods in your Person class to get those values.

```
public int getAge()
{
  return age;
}
```

etc.

Comment: How is it going to solve his problem, did you understand his question ?

Comment: I believe I understood, what would you add to make it clearer?

Comment: @Sambit: The "problem" cannot be solved in Java. The OP should learn to do it the Java way.

Comment: @Sambit I see what you mean now having re-read the question, I shall take more care in future.

Comment: @vanje I understand this approach, but my question was "is it possible to do so in Java".

Answer (score 0):

So I've only done this once and I'm unsure whether the approach I did is the appropriate way.

But my approach was a method called `typeConverter`, which i would give an `object` as `parameter`, then you could take that `parameter` and look what object type it is and then create a new Person, with your value.

Although this approach could cause problems, when your class would have two `integer fields`. But I think you could find a solution for this, by giving it another parameter that defines, which field you'd want to convert it to.

I'm really sorry for my poor english, but I hope you get the principle.

Comment: I understand your approach, but I was really looking for a way to cast the object directly, as in my question.